# Asynchronous methods called inside `-dealloc` could generate unwanted zombie objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

As I was walking through some line of codes I stumbled upon this problem a couple of days ago,

```
- (void)dealloc {
    ...
    [self.postOfficeService deregister:self];
    ...
}
```

Where the de-registration from the *Post Office Service* is an asynchronous operation, even if it's not self evident from the interface as there's no block or function passed to the `postOfficeService`.

The internal implementation of postOfficeService's `-deregister` method is something like that

```
// -deregister:(id)formerSubscriber implementation
//some trivial checks here
// deregister former subscriber
dispatch_asynch(_serialQueue, ^{
    [self.subcribers removeObject:formerSubscriber];
});
...
```

The container, `self.subscribers`, does perfectly its job and contains only weak references. I.e. it is a `NSHashTable`.

As long as the deregistration method got called within the dealloc method, I keep on getting a crash while `postOfficeService` is trying to remove the former subscribers from its list inside that asynch block, which is used for thread safety purposes I guess.
Adding a breakpoint on `[self.subscribers removeObject:formerSubscriber]`, it's possible to notice that the `formerSubscriber` object is always a `NSZombieObject`. That's the reason for crashes.

I know that it's possible to get thread safety for `deregister` method without incurring in this problem - I figure it should be enough use the dispatch_synch in lieu of the dispatch_asynch version
I think this is one of the reason why asynchronous methods shouldn't be called within `dealloc` methods.

But the question is how's possible to constantly get NSZombie objects even if we are in an ARC environment and the container objects is a `NSHashTable` (so it should be working I guess)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is: When dealloc is called, the object will be gone once dealloc returns to its caller (whoever called release when the reference count was 0), and nothing is going to prevent this.

Before ARC, you might have tried to retain an object inside dealloc - doesn't help; once dealloc is called the object will go (and dealloc will be called only once for it, in case you do a retain / release inside dealloc). ARC does the same, just automatically.

Comment: Oh, actually after a while I realised that. Thanks, very clear explanation. Basically it's like trying to avoid someone's death ending up getting a zombie. Sounds like a horror movie but I think it depicts quite well the situation...:)

Answer (score 0):

Using ARC doesn't means all your memory problem magically disappeared.

What happened is

- [obj release] called by ARC

  - [obj dealloc]

    - [obj.postOfficeService deregister:obj]

      - [obj retain] - sorry you can't cancel the deallocation process
      - dispatch_async
  - free(obj) - from this point, obj is a zombie
- GCD scheduling tasks
- dispatch_async execute task

  - use obj - crash

The correct solution is use dispatch_sync to make sure you not trying to use object after it is deallocated. (be careful about dead lock)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't call asynchronous cleanup methods from dealloc. It's just not a good idea. Your `-deregister` should be synchronous.
2. NSHashTable stores pointers - it's the equivalent of __unsafe_unretained or assign - UNLESS it was created using `+weakObjectsHashTable` or the equivalent set of options (`NSHashTableZeroingWeakMemory` and `NSPointerFunctionsObjectPersonality`). If it was not created that way, it is quite likely you will have values pointing to zombie objects.

The question of "why am I getting zombies" is best answered by profiling your application with the Zombies template in Instruments and stimulating the required behavior.

Comment: Like I explained, the `NSHashTable` was created using *weak reference option*. So I didn't have values pointing to zombies objects in the container. The problem was relevant to the `formerSubscriber` reference which is retained by the asynch block after the deallocation.

Comment: What does Instruments tell you?

Comment: I am not using instrument, information debugger provides me are enough to spot this problem. It's pretty systematic.

Comment: Well, Instruments is the preferred tool for diagnosing this problem. The debugger won't tell you enough to diagnose this. Instruments or malloc history will. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that you should probably avoid asynchronous cleanup in your `-dealloc` method. However, it may be possible to fix this by making the parameter to `-deregister:` `__unsafe_unretained`. That method would then have to treat the pointer purely as a opaque value. It must not dereference it or message it. Unfortunately, you don't control the implementation of `NSHashTable` and can't guarantee that. Even if `NSHashTable` could be relied upon, the interface of `-removeObject:` takes an implicitly strong object pointer, so ARC might retain the pointer when it's copied from the unsafe unretained pointer.

You might use the C function API for hash tables (e.g. `NSHashRemove()`) as suggested in the overview for the `NSHashTable` class.

Comment: Good point, but I don't think it may work passing the parameter to the deregistration function as `__unsafe_unretained` because it need s to be dereferenced at some point (i.e, the implementation has to know its value or its absence/presence of value)

Comment: Use the value of the pointer does not dereference the pointer. "Dereference" means to access the pointed-to thing, which it had better not be accessing because that's been deallocated.

Comment: I am not sure I'm getting you...Anyway I tried to do what you suggested me and it doesn't work apparently.